# How to disable autocomplete in Chrome for specific sites

Tags: chrome-for-android, password, auto-fill

When I visit passwords.google.com in Chrome for Android (Marshmallow) I have the option to autocomplete the password.

I would like to disable passoword autocomplete for this site only, or maybe for selected sites, leaving the autocomplete enabled for most sites.

Is it possible to do so? How?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is not possible for an user to disable *autocomplete* for a single site. You can check [this link to disable the feature on Chrome (all sites)](https://www.lifewire.com/disable-autofill-in-google-chrome-4103633) - it is a simple tutorial on how to do it.

However, for a single site, unless you are the website's developer and don't want your users to have this feature, you can't. But, if you are, you can check [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40200269/2405914)

Comment: This is helpful and accurate, but frustrating.  Sounds like it needs a Chrome enhancement request since every other system has some sort of list to control browser behavior by domain/regex.  Looks like I have to edit it in place for now using the dev tools as a user..

Answer (score -1):

Actually you can disable the autofill for usernames and passwords for just one site.  Go to settings in the Chrome browser then to passwords.  Scroll down to find the website that you  do not want autofilled.  Then you hit on the 3 dots and remove it from the list of saved passwords.

Comment: You are not actually disabling autocomplete with this step-by-step, but only removing a saved password...